# SharePoint blue bar isn't showing for end users unless I'm logged in as farm user

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have an issue with SharePoint. For all end users logged in the default blue SharePoint bar that's at the top of the page isn't showing.

However; if I login as farm admin to the SharePoint server this blue bar starts to show for all users again. As soon as I log out or if my session becomes inactive the bar stops showing again for all users.

I'm not sure whats causing this behavior to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Has a custom master page been applied to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:

1. Check the user permissions: Make sure that the affected users have the necessary permissions to access the SharePoint site. You can check the user permissions by going to the site settings and clicking on "Site permissions".
2. Check the user profile service: Verify that the user profile service is running and that the user profiles are being synchronized correctly. You can check the user profile service by going to the Central Administration site and clicking on "Manage service applications".
3. Clear the browser cache: Ask the affected users to clear their browser cache and cookies, and then try accessing the SharePoint site again.
4. Reset the user's site settings: If the issue is only affecting certain users, you can try resetting their site settings by going to the site settings and clicking on "Reset to site definition".
5. Check the custom master page: If a custom master page is being used, make sure that it is not causing the issue. You can try switching to the default master page to see if the issue is resolved.